# Using html select to make ajax refresh to filter table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

As mentioned in the title, I want to know how to make an HTML select box to make an ajax request and use that to filter table. I have searched a lot and was not able to find a good solution. 
How can i get it to filter??

[My source code on jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/5Ld5p6st/):

```
<select>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="tim">Tim</option>
    <option value="cook">Cook</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tim</td>
        <td>2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cook</td>
        <td>2015</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/5Ld5p6st/ is my basic code

Comment: 1. Provide source code in your question, not in a comment to your question. 2. Do not only use jsfiddle. Copy & Paste the code into your question so everybody can read it if the source code is not available anymore on jsfiddle.

Comment: What makes you think you need an AJAX request? AJAX request get data from the server in the background, but in your example, you start with all the data you need.

Comment: then how else can i make that happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example is a little odd because you are filtering down to only one row, but here is how you can make it work.

First, give your `<select>` and `<table>` each an id. I chose something generic:

```
<select id='column-select'>
    <option value="all">All</option>
    <option value="tim">Tim</option>
    <option value="cook">Cook</option>
</select>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<table id='data' border="1">
    <tr>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Tim</td>
        <td>2015</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Cook</td>
        <td>2015</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Now, just use some Jquery to filter out the rows you don't want when the column changes

```
$(document).ready(function() { // Do nothing until document is ready
    $("#column-select").change(function() { // On <select> change... 
        var selection = $("#column-select").val();
        if (selection == "all")
        {
            $("#data tr").show(); // Show all rows
        } else
        {
            $("#data tr").each(function() { // For each row
                if ($(this).find("th").length == 0) // If this is not a heading row
                {
                    if ($(this).find("td").eq(0).text().toLowerCase() == selection)
                    {
                        // Show rows where the first column matches
                        $(this).show(); 
                    } else
                    }
                        // Hide rows where the first column does not match
                        $(this).hide();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s0p7u9r8/1/) to demonstrate.